# Creating a line graph taking data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, d3.js

I tried to create a simple bar chart in D3 taking data from database. The idea is to fetch year and value from the database using the selection buttons of parameters and country and display it in the form of simple bar chart. I have two selection buttons and a submit button. The code for that is like this :

```
      <form action ="data.php" method ="post">

       <tr>
    <th valign="bottom">Select country:</th>
    <td >   
    <select name="country" class="">

        <option value= "NPL">Nepal</option>
         <option value= "IND">India</option>


        </select>

    </td>
    <th valign="bottom">Select parameters:</th>
    <td >   
    <select name="indices" class="">

        <option value= "foodfinal">Vulnerability on food</option>
         <option value= "waterfinal">Vulnerability water </option>


        </select>

    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="submit" class="action" />
        </td>
     </tr>
     </form>
```

Foodfinal and waterfinal are the names of tables in the database called 'Climate'. NPL and IND are the countrycodes. My PHP code ( data.php ) is like this :

```
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="climate";
$country="AFG"; 
$country=$_POST["country"];
 $indices=$_POST["indices"];

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$myquery = "SELECT  `year`, `values` FROM  `$indices` WHERE `countrycode`= '$country'";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);  
include("linegraph.html");   

mysql_close($server);
?>
```

My problem is that linegraph.html had been working well before the use of the selection forms but this time, it only displays the output of data.php which looks like this.

{"year":"1995","values":"0.525999"},{"year":"1996","values":"0.570037"},{"year":"1997","values":"0.563966"},{"year":"1998","values":"0.513896"},{"year":"1999","values":"0.5346"},{"year":"2000","values":"0.552691"},{"year":"2001","values":"0.545319"},{"year":"2004","values":"0.543972"},{"year":"2005","values":"0.543299"},{"year":"2006","values":"0.546682"},{"year":"2007","values":"0.550066"},{"year":"2008","values":"0.549449"},{"year":"2009","values":"0.548832"},{"year":"2010","values":"0.548215"},{"year":"2011","values":"0.547536"},{"year":"2012","values":"0.547536"}]

Would you please help me.

Comment: So do you need to send $data to linegraph.html?  Is that what's supposed to happen here?  Or linegraphe.html uses $data in some way?

Comment: Yes Chris. I need to send all these values( year and values ) to linegraph.html and create a graph.

Comment: I'm quite sure linegraph.html needs this data passed to it as a parameter.  That's not what you're doing here at all.  What does linegraph.html look like?

Comment: Chris, I have used include("linegraph.html"); Is it the right way to do this.

Comment: linegraph.html is a very simple html page.

Comment: So what does linegraph.html do with this data?

Comment: How do you pull the data, you have json encode, are you using Ajax can you post the code for that. it may be your form is just submitting to the page, instead of using the ajax request.

Comment: Chris, linegraph.html creates a bar graph taking this data as the input. @ ArtisticPhoenix,Unfortunately, Ajax hasn't been used.

Comment: @Civa Bhusal  -- your just echoing out json data? I'm not surprised you see it.

Comment: Dear Chris, I haven't posted the JavaScript code in linegraph.html. I didn't post the code because it had been working properly with the ready-made data( data not taken from database, I mean). There is problem only when data is fetched from database.

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix, It looks as if I'm just echoing the data. How can I pass it to linegraph.html successful. Would you please help me ? Do I have to use Ajax ?

Comment: @CivaBhusal Most likely the original linegraph.html was working because the graph data was hard-coded into it.  You need to figure out how to send your dynamic data to the javascript in linegraph file.

Comment: The op is echoing both Json and Html, which is one reason why it doesn't work.  Before was probably just calling the php page from linegraph.html -via- ajax..

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
include("linegraph.html");
```

To  ( as a best practice thing if the "include" is required to display the page just use require )

```
require("linegraph.html");
```

And add at the top of the php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You will probably find your page missing ( at the very least your life will be easier with error reporting turned on )

oh and change this part too,

```
for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

To this

```
  $data = array();
   while ( false !== ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))){
       $data[] = $row;
   }
```

It probably won't fix your problem ( hard to do without the other html page ) but its the preferred way to do this type of loop.

Update: Here you can't pass both html and json the way you are ( just dawned on me ) you have to pick one.  Your problem is a structural one, as you cant do both things at the same time, where does the json data go, it just floats on top of the html? Sorry but it wont work like that, either you already have the html and fill it in with the returned json data, or you build the html with the data already in it and send it back.

change this

```
echo json_encode($data);  
include("linegraph.html");
```

to  ( now you are sending valid json / with the html but you'll have to assemble it client side )

```
 ob_start();
 include("linegraph.html"); 
 $html = ob_get_clean();

$responce = array( 'data'=>$data, 'html'=>$html );
echo json_encode($responce);
```

At the very least your output will change.  Hard to say how to do it ( again ) without the other page.

Ok,,,, when I asked to echo something at the bottom did you do this?

```
echo json_encode($data);  
include("linegraph.html");
mysql_close($server);
echo "works";

?> //id remove this end tag it's not needed and can cause problems if there is space ( line returns ) after it.  Because it will make you json which you may or may not need invalid.
```

Oyyy.  this is .. uhh

```
if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
```

you can just do like this.

```
if ( ! $query ) {
    die ('Query error' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this too didn't work well. Output is the same.

Comment: you put the require in?  Is there any php at all in that other file?

Comment: In that other file, there is no PHP at all.Should I include PHP ?

Comment: There is a Javscript code like this : d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = parseDate(d.year);
        d.values = +d.values;
    });

Comment: put echo 'works'; after the include.  Tell me if it shows up.

Comment: You cant pass html and json the html will invalidate your json data

Comment: After the include, echo works but it doesn't create the graph.

Comment: Updated the last bit at the very least your output should change.

Comment: I tried this too but it also didn't work. It didn't give any output at all.